# pathfinding tower defense NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

i have done some code to allow my capsule to move from waypoint to waypoint and unity isn't picking up that exists [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAHE6.png)

and here is the code my emptybody is called WayPoints all children are called Waypoint through to Waypoint(13)

```
public class WayPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Transform[] points;

    void Awake ()
        {
            points = new Transform[transform.childCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
                {
                    points[i] = transform.GetChild(i);
                }
        }
}
```

Edit: after changing to list is now coming up with error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjNut.png)

new code:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
        public float speed = 10f;
        public static List<Vector3[]> points = new List<Vector3>();

        private Transform target;
        private int wavepointIndex = 0;

        void start ()
            {
                target = WayPoints.points[0];
            }

void Awake ()
    {
        points = new List<Vector3>();
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
            {
                points[i] = transform.GetChild(i).position;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Code provides doesn’t match error.

Comment: **TYPO!**: You have `void start ()` instead of `void Start()` so Unity will not find it and not call it => `target` is never assigned ... you didn't show us the affected code btw which would be in `Update` within the `Enemy` component ...

Answer (score -1):

I don't have access to Unity to test but reading your code I would alter to work with an array or list of Vector3 objects.

Something along the lines of (not tested)

```
public static List<Vector3[]> points = new List<Vector3>();

    void Awake ()
        {
            points = new List<Vector3>();
            for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
                {
                    points[i] = transform.GetChild(i).position;
                }
        }
```